# How to handle n number of parameter in Angular2/4 router?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular2-router, angular2-router3

In my application, there can be n number of params in the URLn and then it can have an optional following pattern too.
For example, the URLs can be

`http://example.com/{param1}`

`http://example.com/{param1}/constant/{id}`

`http://example.com/{param1}/{param2}/constant/{id}`

`http://example.com/{param1}/{param2}`

`http://example.com/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}`

`http://example.com/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}/constant/{id}`

etc

How do I construct my routing module for these kind of URLs?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like so?

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  { path: 'api/whatever/:id1/', component: ComponentName}
  { path: 'api/whatever/:id1/dosomething/:id2', component: ComponentName}
  { path: 'api/whatever/:id1/:id2', component: ComponentName}
  { path: 'api/whatever/:id1/:id2/dosomething/:id3/dosomemore', component: ComponentName}
])
```

Comment: Something like that, yes. But :id1/:id2 are not always just :id1/:id2, it may be :id1/:id2/:id3/..../idn

Comment: So you want to be able to specify an indefinite amount of ids? This wouldn't be possible from what I know. You'd need to specify each route as per my example I'm afraid. I'm not too sure what you're trying to achieve by this, if you give me an example I can maybe suggest an alternative way?